# How to run section of VBA code in Outlook only once?

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like my VBA code in Outlook's "ThisOutlookSession" module to display a message box on the first occurrence of an event only, even if the event occurs in subsequent sessions. All the ways I have found online to achieve this are excel specific and involve changing a value of a cell and then checking this value, is there an equivalent in outlook or another way to achieve this?

I believe this could be achieved using the VBIDE library to change a variable value in the VBA code, however I would prefer not to do this.

Comment: Can't you just use an external file?

Comment: If on Windows: https://vba-corner.livejournal.com/3054.html

Comment: ...or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/savesetting-statement